# Cloudwatch insights, query to graph by value of JSON values?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I've got a JSON object in my logs that shows up as the following:

```
"result":{
   "totalRecords":8,
   "bot":3,
   "member":5,
   "message":0,
   "reaction":0,
   "success":0,
   "error":0,
   "unknown":8
}
```

I'm trying to write a logs insights query to graph the values of each of those keys. Essentially I want a line chart with a different line for the value of each of the keys. Currently I have my query as the following:

```
fields result.bot, result.error, result.member, result.message, result.reaction, 
result.success, result.totalRecords, result.unknown
| stats count(result.bot), count(result.error), 
 count(result.member),count(result.message),
 count(result.reaction),count(result.success),
 count(result.totalRecords), count(result.unknown) by bin(30s)
```

This returns the count of how many times the keys show up in the logs, but not the values.

[image: Graph]

What I need to know is what you use to get the value of a given key. I tried appending a `.0` for example `count(result.totalRecords.0)` as was suggested in the AWS docs but it doesn't return any value. What is the query for the value of a key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on documentation

> Counts the log events. count() (or count(*)) counts all events returned by the query, while count(fieldName) counts all records that include the specified field name.

You can write instead

```
stats sum(result.bot), sum(result.error) by bin (30s)
```

etc. This will give you sum of those values over 30s periods. You can shorten the period if you want greater granularity.